# React Avoid Re-Render for Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I am using Hooks and how can I avoid from re-render? My purpose of asking this quesiton , I am using scroll for overflow item from div height and when I focus on a item  using onMouseOver, my funtional component is rendering itself and scroll is returning initial position. Therefore I dont delete last item of div. Could you any advice to avoid re-rendering ?

My component :

```
 import React from 'react'

  type removeDisplayItem = {
    dataId: number;
    display: boolean
}

  const PlayerCalendar = () => {
  const [removeDisplayData, setRemoveDisplayData] = useState<removeDisplayItem>({ dataId: -1, display: false })

    const handleRemove = (dataId: number, display: boolean) => {

        const removeData = {
            dataId: dataId,
            display: display
        }
       
        setRemoveDisplayData(removeData)
    }

    const renderScheduleContentCell = (data: scheduleItem) => {
      
        return (
            <>
                <div className="cell-content-wrapper" style={removeDisplayData.dataId === data.id && removeDisplayData.display === true ? { display: "none" } : { display: "flex" }}
                    onMouseOver={() => handleDisplayRemove(data.id, true)}>

                    <div className="start-time-text">{moment(data.startTime).format("HH:mm")}</div>
                    <div className="dash"> - </div>
                    <div className="end-time-text"> {moment(data.endTime).format("HH:mm")} </div>

                </div>

                <div className="cell-content-wrapper" onMouseLeave={() => handleDisplayRemove(data.id, false)}
                    style={removeDisplayData.dataId === -1 ? { display: "none" } : removeDisplayData.dataId === data.id && removeDisplayData.display === true ? { display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", backgroundColor: "#8c9296", color: "white", cursor: "pointer" } : { display: "none" }}
                    onClick={() => setCalendarRemoveItemConfirm(true)}>

                    <div className="dash"> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div className="start-time-text">Remove</div>
                    <div className="end-time-text"><i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></div>

                </div>

            </>
        )
    }

 return (
          {renderScheduleContentCell(exampleData)}
      )
  }
  
  export default PlayerCalendar;
```

Comment: React rerenders exactly as many times as your changes to the internal data warrant, so the answer is really "by making sure to only change things when they need to". Things shouldn't rerender if there is no difference in the virtual dom.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`memo HOC`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and wrap it around `PlayerCalendar` component.

`React.memo` can be use to `optimize` your component. When you have the same `props / state` it can be used to `memoize the data`.